# How to ensure rendering of digits as arabic numerals on Windows 10?

Tags: c++, winapi, numbers, windows-10

My application allows users to customize UI by selecting a user preferred language. It usually works great, except that on Windows 10, say, if a user locale is picked as, say, `Cambodian` in Windows Control Panel:

[image]

But then if the user in my app's UI picks `US English`, I can't seem to find a way to render it with "US English numbers." On Windows 8.1 it used to end up looking as such, no matter what locale is picked:

[image]

As my assumption was that one doesn't need to translate numbers. But on Windows 10, that same control ends up looking as such:

[image]

Note that its text is set up using just this call:

```
::SetWindowText(m_hWnd, L"1000");
```

So I am curious, is there any way to keep numbers rendered as the arabic numerals:

[image]

Comment: "*My application allows users to customize UI by selecting a user preferred language*" - and how are you allowing them to do that exactly? And why would you want your UI to not follow the user's selected language settings from the system level?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Mostly by substituting text for controls & for date/time, by changing LCIDs.

Comment: *SPECIFICALLY*, what are you doing to change your UI's language so it is different than the system language?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Just what I posted above.

Comment: That is just a description. This is a programming Q&A site.  Please provide a [mcve] of **actual code** to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you doing anything to change the threads locale?

Comment: @Anders: I tried originally to call `SetProcessPreferredUILanguages` but it doesn't seem to have any effect on how everything is rendered in those controls, so I took it out.

Comment: Also, since you brought this up, I tried calling `SetThreadPreferredUILanguages`, `SetThreadLocale`, `SetThreadUILanguage` all to no result. There must be something else new to Win10.

Comment: Do you get the same result in a plain edit control (or e.g. a static control) or does it only happen in an edit control with `ES_NUMBER` set?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Yes. To repro, create a dialog-based project in VS, add an [edit control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458(v=vs.85).aspx), or a [static ctrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760769(v=vs.85).aspx) with numbers. (Btw, any other Win32 ctrls with numbers are also affected.) Then I'm using a Win10 VM. Go to (old) Control Panel -> Region and change it to what I showed on the screenshot. Run the test app. You should see my results. (Note that, to the best of my knowledge, this doesn't seem to affect numbers under Win8.1.)

Comment: Oh, shoot. Forgot to mention. I'm testing it on `Win10 v1803, build 17133.1`. It's a fast ring insider build. But, it might be the same for the regular non-insider builds as well.

Comment: If all controls do it then maybe it's something to do with the selected font?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Yes, probably, but I'm not changing the font at all.

Comment: Maybe you should be!

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Changing the font is not really a practical solution. Aside from just a trivial question of "which font type to use", there's also an issue of changing the font in `MessageBox` dialogs, and other common controls, which is not as trivial as it sounds. So before I even consider doing that, I'm still hoping to find a "documented" way to do it in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

This issue goes much deeper than basic controls, it happens inside GDI and also affects `DrawText` and `TextOut`. The only documented way around it is to call `ExtTextOut` with the `ETO_NUMERICSLATIN` flag (or use Uniscribe to render text).

> [This behavior is completely by design](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2008/06/16/8603298.html)
>
> these flags only modify U+0030 -- U+0039, as needed
>
> Becsause the truth is that GDI doesn't give a crap about formatting or really anything related to locales, with one signle exception: Digit Substitution
>
> Any time you go to render text it will grab those digit substitution settings in the user locale (including the user override information) and use the info to decide how to display numbers.

Another thing that seems to work is to force a custom font with the GREEK_CHARSET charset. That charset triggers a [font association magic feature](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2007/07/11/3815916.html). (EE_CHARSET also seems to work for English text). You would probably have to try to pick the best charset for each of your languages if you are going to do this but you cannot use ANSI_CHARSET nor DEFAULT_CHARSET.

If don't know why this only happens in Windows 10 but it really seems like a bug in certain places. In Explorer for example it will display "7-Zip" as "៧-Zip" etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info, man. I'll look into it. Like I said somewhere in the comments above, my main assumption in doing localization was that digits (the way we understand and use them in the Roman-derived cultures) are immutable and are not translatable. Well, I guess I was wrong. Some languages translate digits as well. But, having said that, you can't just blindly `grep` out all digits with whatever locale dictates instead, either. A good example are trademarks, such as 7-Zip, where that should not be done. So thanks, it is a perfect example.